# Should I consolidate multiple identical VMs into BSD jails?

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory, freebsd, openfire

We run a number of [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) XMPP/Jabber servers. Due to the way Openfire works, we cannot easily run multiple Openfire instances on one server, so I have 5 identical VMware ESXi VMs, each with CentOS, MySQl, Java, and Openfire. They're the exact same, except for their IP addresses, the actual Openfire MySQL database and it's config file.

I am wondering if this is the optimal configuration, or if it would be better to move these VMs to a single FreeBSD machine and put each one inside a FreeBSD jail. Specifically, I am wondering if the benefit of VMWare's [Transparent Page Sharing (TPS)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021095) would outweight the cost of running 5 identical OSes. Would I end up using less memory with one large FreeBSD machine and java running in bsd jails?